# Custom collection view hover effect

Tags: ios, swift

Can we set collection hover effect on particular cell?
As per below image I set 5th cell as hover but as shown in image how to set 6th cell behind the 5th cell?

[image]

```
override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
   let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
   attributes.size = preferredCellSize
   var centerX : CGFloat? = 0

   if indexPath.item  >= 5 {               
      centerX  = preferredCellSize.width / 2.0 + CGFloat(indexPath.item) * (centerDiff) + 20.0               
   } else {     
      centerX = preferredCellSize.width / 2.0 + CGFloat(indexPath.item) * centerDiff
   }

   let centerY = collectionView!.bounds.height / 2.0
   attributes.center = CGPoint(x:centerX!, y:centerY)
   attributes.zIndex = indexPath.item

   return attributes
}
```

Comment: Do you want to apply the hover as an effect of an action? (eg: the user touched a cell)

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini No, I just want on particular cell without any action

Comment: do they share the same section?

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini yes which all are in one section